# Create slightly modificate copy of an element in XSL

Tags: xml, regex, xslt, transformation

I would like to transform a XML document and make some regex/replace on some attribute.

Here is the XML:

```
<node1>
    <node2>
        <item attrbitueToModify="Blabla"></item>
    </node2>
    <node3>
        <node4>
            <item attrbitueToModify="Blabla"></item>
        </node4>
    </node3>
<node1>
```

Here the transformation

```
<xsl:template match="*" >
    <node1>
        <xsl:for-each select="attribute::*" >
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="fn:name() = 'attrbitueToModify'">
                    <xsl:attribute name="attrbitueToModify" ><xsl:value-of select="replace(., 'blabla', 'replaced')" /></xsl:attribute>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="." />
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each>

        <xsl:apply-templates select="*" />
    </node1>
</xsl:template>
```

I don't know how to change `<node1>` from the transformation to something dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

I find it!

```
<xsl:template match="*" >
    <xsl:element name="{name(.)}">
        <xsl:for-each select="attribute::*" >
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="fn:name() = 'attrbitueToModify'">
                    <xsl:attribute name="attrbitueToModify" ><xsl:value-of select="replace(., 'blabla', 'replaced')" /></xsl:attribute>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="." />
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each>

        <xsl:apply-templates select="*" />
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Charles, you're on the right lines. But the "canonical" solution to this problem is more like this:

```
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@attributeToModify">
  <xsl:attribute name="{name()}" select="replace(., 'blabla', 'replaced')"/>
</xsl:template>
```

The first template rule is known as an "identity template" because it copies everything unchanged, unless there is a more specific rule to say otherwise. In XSLT 3.0 you don't need to write out the identity template, you can instead declare:

```
<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
```